# Non-Latin characters are underscores under RESTful Google Translate API v2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I'm trying to use Google's translate method from its Translation API as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate), but for some reason the translations I get replace non-Latin characters with underscores.

For instance, with curl on the command-line:

```
$ curl -X POST 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/?source=en&target=de&q=Practicing+diligently+each+day+means+inevitable+improvement.&key=MY_API_KEY'  
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "T_glich flei_ig zu _ben, bedeutet unausweichliche Verbesserung."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Compare to the English-to-German result from translate.google.com:

```
Täglich fleißig zu üben, bedeutet unausweichliche Verbesserung.
```

It's especially bad when the target is a language like Japanese, which doesn't contain Latin characters:

```
$ curl -X POST 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/?source=en&target=ja&q=Practicing+diligently+each+day+means+inevitable+improvement.&key=MY_API_KEY' 
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "______________________________________________________"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Maybe this is a trial account limitation?  Nothing I've seen in this docs would indicate this, however.

Comment: have you tried running it from an application? perhaps curl doesn't know what to do in your terminal

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I think it is a terminal issue, based on pasting the Google translation into my prompt, so that just leaves to to troubleshoot the terminal and post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat embarrassingly, this was actually just an issue with `tmux`, the terminal multiplexer I was using to read the output of every call I made to the Translation API, both with `curl` and with the printed output of the code I was writing.

As per [this Ask Ubuntu answer to someone else's `tmux` question](https://askubuntu.com/a/746846), this is fixable by explicitly telling `tmux` to launch with UTF-8 support, i.e., `tmux -u`.

Thanks both to Dai and Daniel for pointing to a potential terminal issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a string-encoding issue.

I assume your HTTP request body is being sent using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - **which does not support characters above `0x7F` (128) as literal text**, see here: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded and charset="utf-8"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819502/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-and-charset-utf-8)

I suggest:

1. `POST` with an explicit `Content-Type: application/json` header with the `charset=utf-8` field set. (`x-www-form-urlencoded` does not support the `charset` field).
2. Ensure your terminal is using UTF-8
3. Also take a look using a tool like Wireshark, or create the request in JavaScript using `fetch` and use Chrome's Developer Tools' Network tab's "Copy as cURL (Bash)" command to get the terminal command to use.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with the following request and it worked well:

```
curl -X POST "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{
        'q': 'Practicing diligently each day means inevitable improvement.',
        'source': 'en',
        'target': 'de'
}"
```

Giving this output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Täglich fleißig zu üben, bedeutet unausweichliche Verbesserung."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And for the Japanese output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "毎日熱心に練習することは避けられない改善を意味します。"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps